# How can I scan newline in a sentence without fgets();

Tags: c

First, take a character, ch as input.
Then take the string, s as input.
Lastly, take the sentence sen as input.

This was the task provided by hackerrank and ive heard that it does not accept fgets()

```
int main(){

   char ch, s[50], sen[100];

  scanf("%c%s%[^n]%s", &ch, &s, &sen);
  printf("%c\n%s%s", ch, s, sen);
    return 0;
}
```

this is my code and there's a problem in the scan function - "%[^n]%s" this is wrong and it is supposed to be "%[^\n]%s" but somehow it works and if i correct it, it gives me an error.

What went wrong?

Comment: The last `%s` won't read a sentence, only a word.

Comment: "What went wrong?" You either ignored warnings or (in case you didn't get any warnings) used wrong compiler options. For `gcc` at least use the options `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`. In your `scanf` the number of `%` doesn't match the number of arguments that follows. Besides that there are type mismatch.

Answer (score 1):

> What went wrong?

`scanf("%c%s%[^n]%s", &ch, &s, &sen);` is bad.

- Code not compiled with a well enabled compiler that would complain about mis-matched types.  `"%s"` expect a `char *`.  `&s` is not a `char *`.
- Code has 4 specifiers yet only 3 following arguments.
- Return value not checked.
- Missing widths risk buffer overflow.
- Code does not limit to 1 line as `"%s"` consumes any number of leading white-space including multiple `'\n'`.

---

To robustly read a single line of user input via `scanf()` is non-trivial.  Most attempts have many holes - even if it works for some test cases.